# Spring Data MongoDB: how to implement multi-tenancy in CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I designed my DB to support multi-tenancy: every document has a reference to a `Tenant`.

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB to implement data access logic and I need to handle document retrieval by tenant in my repositories.

Is there a common approach to implement it? Do I need to override every method of `CrudRepository` to match only documents from a certain tenant or is there some facilities to achieve this?

Comment: maybe this is interessting for you: https://github.com/Loki-Afro/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb

Comment: @user3415653 this is for multiple db applications, I have a shared DB for all the tenants

Comment: Implement a service layer, get the current user inside your retrieval method and query for all objects matching your criteria + the user's Id in the tenant field. For additional security, you could implement a Spring Security [@PostFilter rule](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#filtering-using-prefilter-and-postfilter) checking wether the tenant field matches the current user's Id.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg your suggestion is really good. I will elaborate it. thanks a lot.

Comment: I have implemented multi-tenancy in spring-data, mongo db.. https://github.com/vikashnitk50/spring-mongo-db-poc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally decided to implement multi-tenancy at service layer as suggested by **Markus W Mahlberg** in his comment.

At repository level I created a `findByTenantIdAndId` query to check if a certain entity/document `id` belongs to the proper tenant.

I have a custom implementation of `UserDetails` interface, storing `tenantId` for logged user. I retrieve logged user at service layer via `SecurityContextHolder`.